# Gboard ruined my typing experience, how can I change it back?

Tags: languages, gboard

My phone just got the new Gboard, and to be honest, I haven't noticed much of an improvement. Maybe I don't use its many celebrated features as much as I should.

However, I have one big problem with it the way it is. I use my phone to mainly type two languages: Norwegian and English. Before the update, I would switch between them by the touch of a button (the globe icon next to the space bar), and for those rare occations I needed something else, I could momentarily enable them in the settings. I used the English layout for writing English, and the Norwegian language to write Norwegian. This way, the moment I begin to write, the swipe function knows which dictionary to test for what I'm trying to type, and everything works nicely.

However, with the new Gboard, it can do both languages at once. Apparently, the internet is happy that you don't have to manually switch, but I am more annoyed at the fact that when I begin swiping, the keyboard doesn't know which dictionary to use, so I can swipe all I want without any words coming out. I have to manually type a few words first before it gets the idea, and from there it works nicely. It also makes it much more difficult to mix both languages into a single small text.

How can I get back to manually switching between languages? Is there a setting I've missed, or do I *have* to roll back to an earlier version?

I'm on an LG Nexus 4, running Android 5.1.1, and Gboard version 6.0.69